# Using regex to validate email address in powershell

Tags: regex, email, powershell, outlook

So i made a script that parses a .msg file in outlook and ommits the result. The whole scripts works except for when I receive an email from inside the network (we use Active Directory) is when i get a result similar to this: /O=Business/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=MIKEF
otherwise for emails outside the network I get email@email.com. I would like to to validate this this with regex that way it would take the name in the CN=" " and adds it to my @email.com

```
$MSGFILEPATH = '\\srv01\FTP\EmailtoSupportPortal\Testing'
$MSGCOMPLETED= '\\srv01\FTP\EmailtoSupportPortal\Testing\Completed'
Function MSGFiles {
Get-ChildItem $MSGFILEPATH -Filter *.msg|`
ForEach-Object{
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
    $body = $msg.Body
    $SEM = $msg.SenderEmailAddress
    $Subject = $msg.Subject 
    $SEM
    }
}
MSGFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the MailItem.SenderEmailType property. If it is "EX", use MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress (be prepared to handle nulls/errors).
Otherwise use the SenderEmailAddress property the way you do that now.

Comment: I guess you could say this is a dirty fix but so far this is what I got: `$msg.SenderEmailAddress -replace "/O=ELCORINC/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN="` which removes everything but leaves 'MIKEF'

How can I add @email.com to MIKEF with regex?

Comment: It will not work in all cases. Why do you need a hack if a perfectly valid solution is available?

Comment: method does not work because of old outlook version, so i was trying to find work around

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2003

Comment: You need to have at least 2007 to be able to use PropertyAccessor. Is using Redemption an option?

Comment: unfortunately not I dont have permission

Comment: I don't think you have much of a choice - Outlook 2003 is no longer supported by MS anyway...